# How to get all the users from /etc/passwd which doesn't have a home directory

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to get all users whose home directories are mentioned in /etc/passwd but are not present in /home.

The below code gives me all the home directories which are not present in /home but are present in /etc/passwd.

```
cut -d":" -f6 /etc/passwd | grep home | sort | 
    while read dir; do [ -e "$dir" ] || echo Missing $dir; done
```

How do I get the list of corresponding users from the first column and create the corresponding /home directory using `mkhomedir_helper(user)` one by one from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep the username in the data that you read. You don't need to use `cut`, `read` can split the input into fields and assign them to variables.

```
grep /home/ /etc/passwd | sort -t: -k6 | while IFS=: read -r username _ _ _ _ dir _
do
    if ! [ -d "$dir" ]
    then 
        echo "Username $username missing $dir"
        mkhomedir_helper "$username"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 6):

Other implementation of Barmar's solution:

```sh
getent passwd | sort -t: -k6 | while IFS=: read -r u _ _ _ _ d _
do
  if [[ "$d" =~ ^/home/ ]] && ! [[ -d "$d" ]]
    then printf 'Directory %q missing for user: %q\n' "$d" "$u"
  fi
done
```

Using `getent` allow to pull the same data whenever it is a file or an NIS (Network Information Service).

`[[ "$d" =~ ^/home/ ]]` ensure the home directory starts with `/home` by matching it against Extended Regular Expression. `^/home/`

Comment: thank you... I think you need to put '!' in the if statement for it to find missing directory.